# Timings constraints when interfacing an external ADC with an FPGA

Tags: adc, fpga, timing-analysis

I am currently using a Trion T8 FPGA to receive and store data from an external ADC, the ADC08100. The FPGA uses the internal PLL to generate a 100 MHz (10 ns period) clock signal, and its logic runs at that frequency. This same clock signal is used to clock the ADC, as such:

[image: System Architecture]

The issue lies in the timing of the ADC, which indicates that, for the worst case, the data lines are valid only after 8.5ns (T_OD) of the rising edge. It also indicates that the data lines are held valid for 4.4ns (T_OH) after the rising edge. This means that the only valid window for the FPGA to read the data lines is 8.5ns after the rising edge or no longer than 4.4ns after the rising edge.
I am trying to understand how to set this up in the constraints file of the FPGA (SDC) but am having issues understanding exactly how to specify this condition, where the FPGA must read the data in less than 4.4ns after the rising edge.

Here is the timing diagram of the ADC08100:

[image: ADC08100 Timing Diagram]

If I understand correctly, there are two delays that I also must consider.

1. The time that it takes for the clock signal to go from the logic core, to the GPIO, to the ADC - D_CLK
2. The time that it takes for the data signal to go from the ADC, to the GPIO, to the logic core - D_DATA

In order to be able to read the data on the rising edge, D_CLK + T_OH + D_DATA < 10 ns and the data lines must be captured in 4.4 ns.

In order to be able to read the data on the falling edge, D_CLK + T_OH + D_DATA < 15 ns and the data lines must be captured in (5 ns - 4.4 ns + D_CLK)

Please tell me if this is what I should be thinking or if I am completly off.